# Android - Add url for each item in gridview to download the file from defined url

Tags: android, url, gridview, download

Hello to all great developers and helpers. I need some help. 
I have gridview with defined icons. (They stored in application, i dont need to download them from internet).

1st Question - How to add textview (i.e Name of the Icon) to the existing gridview adapter?

2nd Question (Most important, first priority to solve) - How can i add specified urls for each item and clicking on it user will download specified file? (E.g - My gridview shows Skins, clicking on it user will be able to download the skin which he choose.) 
I tried many ways, cannot find the solution. 
Something like that:

```
    public void prepareList()
{
    listHttp = new ArrayList();
    listHttp.add("http://yoursite/file1.apk");
    listHttp.add("http://yoursite/file2.apk");
    listHttp.add("http://yoursite/file3.apk");
```

SkinsActivity.class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SkinsActivity extends Activity {
com.htc.widget.HtcAlertDialog.Builder builder;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    /**
     * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
     * */
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {


            HtcAlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new HtcAlertDialog.Builder(SkinsActivity.this);

          //   Setting Dialog Title
           alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Installation");

         //   Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to install this skin?");

        //    Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_about);

          //   Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

            //    Write your code here to invoke YES event
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            });

            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
          alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
             }
         });

            // Showing Alert Message
           alertDialog.show();


        }
    });
}
```

ImageAdapter.class (Gridviewadapter)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sense5, R.drawable.sense5red,
        R.drawable.concrete, R.drawable.graphite,
        R.drawable.sense5_full,

};




// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 180));
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To add `TextView` you can create your own layout and inflate it dynamically in `getView` method of the adapter.
2. To manage the link part you can have a String array and in `onItemClick` method you can get the specific url using `position` parameter and use it as you want

-Edit-

xml you can use for the `TextView` part

my_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appIcon"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/albumstack1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/appIcon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:text="My Application name"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can inflate it in the getView method using

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
           ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.appNameTextView)).setText("put your text here");
            ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.appIcon)).setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    }
    return v;
}
```

For the link part you had listHttp in your question, you can use the same in

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
        /**your code**/
        //This is the string you need for the url, do whatever you want to do with this string
        String urlForApp = listHttp.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but can you explain a bit more? maybe provide some example..
Thank you

Comment: Thanks but confusing.. lets do like this. I dont have those links now in my code, so what is the best way to implement them into my existing code, then onclickevent downloadmanager will start downloading this files (each icon have own correspondent url, how to store them etc) to stock path provided by downloadmanager (sdcard/Downloads) ?

Comment: You will have to use Asynch task to download the apk. You can find the code on google.